# When setting a field to None in the Data Source, do you have to drag it onto a control with a data context?

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, data-binding

Something we're trying to figure out is how to specify the type of control we want to drag fields from databases, or entity framework objects, onto the WPF window, user control, page. In particular, we're thinking of using Telerik controls, and they don't seem to be assignable to the Data Source view in Visual Studio. But if we set the field to None, do we then drag it onto some control that can be data bound?

Comment: In WPF... no one uses that... and everyone writes their XAML by hand. Having the VS designer do the XAML for you is equivalent to doing web applications in FrontPage. Ask a web developer if they prefer to use FrontPage versus creating the HTML manually in, say a notepad. WPF is not the kind of framework where you will drag and drop everything in Visual Studio. The learning curve is steep, admittedly it's not for beginners nor draganddroppers.

Comment: You may think.. *"how is this an advancement?"* *"In winforms I could drag and drop.."*. I can bet my salary I can do a CRUD screen in half the time it takes a draganddropper do the same in winforms. Keeping resolution independence and the code really really clean (MVVM).

Comment: By the way, directly binding your UI to your data model doesn't `always` make sense. In some cases there must be a ViewModel in between, if you want for example to create complex interaction logic. the Model is not the right place for that, and neither is the UI (code behind). Therefore you must have a ViewModel to place that kind of logic.

Comment: I hear what you're saying, HighCore, but my coworker will NOT accept doing any other way than to drag the controls from the data source. Period. So, we must find a way to do it.

Comment: then go back to winforms. WPF is not for draganddroppers. It is a complex technology not suitable for people who don't want to get involved in the technical aspects of it. And no you will not find a way to do that. Microsoft has not put much effort in the Visual Studio designer because no one actually cares about that. Neither will in the future because they're now focusing in WinRT.

Comment: by the way, creating a binding in XAML takes less that 1 second, versus the multiple lines of code you need to do the same in winforms in code behind. I don't see why anybody would want some crappy designer-defined XAML instead of creating their own. The XAML produced by the Visual Studio designer is rather ugly, loses a LOT of resolution independence (because the designer positions the thing  absolutely) and is completely unmaintainable. You seem to be missing the point.

Comment: I appreciate what you're saying, and think I do get the point. I've seen the XAML it produces and agree it's convoluted. (I admit I wasn't aware of the fact that it places the control absolutely.) But my coworker is adamant about using drag-and-drop. Thank you for your help.